# Houdini - Issue with skeletal Meshs and UV Maps

Tags: uv-mapping, skeletal-mesh, houdini

I'm having issues with skeletal meshes and UV Maps.
Here is my model:
[Model screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omfe0.png)

The idea is to use the spheres as the pivot points and I don't want any deformation.

[Network screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlV6h.png)

This is my network, as you can see I have 3 bones for my rig and 3 geometry nodes which corresponds to the 3 parts of my model.

Segment1 : Top cylinder with sphere
Segment2 : Middle cylinder and sphere
Handle2 : bottom cylinder

Here is the content of the segment2 geometry:
[segment2 geometry node content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE6bY.png)

This bone system seems to be working just fine without deformation however my issue is with the UV Map. Because I have 3 separate geometries, that also means I have 3 separate UV Maps.

Obviously, when I unwrap them, I have overlapping UVs:
[UV MAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnPu1.png)

Which results into texture redundancy once in UE4:
[preview in UE4 of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miDI2.jpg)

One of my attempts was to have only one geometry node and the UV Unwrapping happening after a merge:
[network of my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoTNC.png)

The animation works perfectly in Houdini.
The issue is this doesn't get recognized as a Skeletal mesh in UE4.

Would you have any idea how to share the same UV Map between geometries without having to place each island manually myself so that they don't overlap?

Cheers,